# Use of "get" in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

The background to this is that I have some legacy code which uses plyr in a few places, and until a couple of days ago, plyr had not been updated to make it work with R 3.5.  I think that is a bit of a signal of diminishing support for plyr, hence I am looking into changing the plyr commands to dplyr.  The ddply commands in the legacy code involve some "get" commands to refer to columns whose names are contained in a variable.  A direct translation would involve code of the type below (a contrived example, but it shows the point).  It seems to work, and keeps it closest to the original code, but are there any pitfalls in doing this?  I get the impression it is not the manufacturer-approved way to program with dplyr!
Example code:

```
library("dplyr")
testFunction <- function(dataset, groupcol, varcol){
  summaryTable <- dataset %>% 
    group_by(get(groupcol)) %>%
    summarise(mean_var = mean(get(varcol)),
              sd_var = sd(get(varcol)))
  return(summaryTable)
}
testGroup <- "cyl"
testVar <- "mpg"
testFunction(mtcars, testGroup, testVar)
```

Being a dinosaur, I am tempted by the alternative of translating from plyr back into base-R (with no "get"s in sight), e.g. something like:

```
fossilFunction <- function(dataset, groupcol, varcol){
  z <- by(dataset, dataset[ , testGroup], function(x){
    c(mean_var = mean(x[ , varcol]), 
      sd_var = sd(x[ , varcol]))
  })
  z <- do.call(rbind, z)
  data.frame(rownames(z), z, row.names = NULL)
}
testGroup <- "cyl"
testVar <- "mpg"
fossilFunction(mtcars, testGroup, testVar)
```

Speed is not an issue in this case.  However, must try to look forwards, not back...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of `dplyr` allows for inserting variables into function calls using the bang-bang operator (`!!`). The `get()` function should be avoided. You can fix your function in the following way

```
testFunction <- function(dataset, groupcol, varcol){
  groupcol <- as.name(groupcol)
  varcol <- as.name(varcol)
  summaryTable <- dataset %>% 
    group_by(!!groupcol) %>%
    summarise(mean_var = mean(!!varcol),
              sd_var = sd(!!varcol))
  return(summaryTable)
}
testGroup <- "cyl"
testVar <- "mpg"
testFunction(mtcars, testGroup, testVar)
```

See the [programming with dplyr vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks.  Out of interest, and with reference to my original question, why should the get function be avoided?  Just dogma, or is there a functional reason?  I suppose bang-bang is 3 characters shorter than get!

Comment: @Knackiedoo I guess it might be more of a style guide recommendation. It's not easy to show an example where you get the wrong result, but when using `get()`, it's not always clear where exactly you are trying to pull a particular variable from. Generally when i see `get()/assign()` in R code it's from other people copying algorithms from other languages and not really doing things "the R way." Using symbols and expressions (or exprs) or quosures as encouraged by dplyr allows for more flexible code and behaves better when using expressions more complicated than a single column name.

Comment: The vignette you linked contains nothing about either get or !!

Comment: @StefanoBorini This was answered back in 2018 when things were different. The recommendation now is to use {{}} rather than !! In most cases. Using get() was never recommended so it was never there. The vignette is up to date.

Comment: @StefanoBorini If you have a specific problem or question for your own you should ask your own question on this site  rather than trying to have a conversation in the comments. There’s no need to make such sweeping disparaging remakes about the language.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sym` to convert it to a `symbol` this if we are passing a string variable and then evaluate with `!!`

```
testFunction <- function(dataset, groupcol, varcol){

varcol <- rlang::sym(varcol)
 dataset %>% 
    group_by(!! rlang::sym(groupcol)) %>%
    summarise(mean_var = mean(!! varcol),
          sd_var = sd(!! varcol))

 }
testFunction(mtcars, testGroup, testVar)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl mean_var sd_var
#  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     4     26.7   4.51
#2     6     19.7   1.45
#3     8     15.1   2.56
```

---

Or without using `rlang`, we can also pass strings into `group_by_at` and `summarise_at`

```
testFunction <- function(dataset, groupcol, varcol){
 dataset %>% 
    group_by_at(groupcol)%>%
    summarise_at(vars(varcol),  funs(mean, sd))


 }

testFunction(mtcars, testGroup, testVar)
```

Comment: Thanks.  The answer from MrFlick is similar but without converting to a symbol before using bang bang, and it appears to work.  Is there a particular reason or circumstance under which it is necessary to convert to a symbol first?   group_by_at is a good suggestion, but in the real cases in question the summarise_at will not cut it, since the summary is in reality much more complex than applying a single function to all the varcols.

Comment: @Knackiedoo  `as.name` is converting to symbol `str(as.name(testGroup))#
 symbol cyl`

Comment: Regarding the conditions where it needs to changed to symbol, if the passing argument is a character string.  If it is a unquoted string, it can be converted to quosure with `enquo` and then do the `!!`

Comment: OK, I understand. I am pretty sure the theoretical encoding issue with as.name is  unlikely to be an issue, so I will stick with the base function instead of sym.  Just for interest,  am curious why "get" meets such disapproval.  It is one step less, and appears to work.

Comment: @Knackiedoo  Sorry, I dont follow the issue you talked about.  `sym` is from the tidyverse set of packages.  `get` may get into problems if you don't specify the correct environment or location of the object

Comment: I was just referring to sym help "Contrarily to as.name(), they convert the strings to the native encoding beforehand".  I'll take your word for the potential for environment / location issues with get.  Just trying to learn!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I go against some of the orthodoxy here and I do just use `get` for some of these situations:

```
testFunction <- function(dataset, groupcol, varcol){
  dataset %>% 
    group_by(get(groupcol)) %>%
    summarise(mean_var = mean(get(varcol)),
              sd_var = sd(get(varcol)))
}
```

Alternatively, I use double-brackets `[[` on the `.` or `.data` objects:

```
testFunction <- function(dataset, groupcol, varcol){
  dataset %>% 
    group_by(.data[[groupcol]]) %>%
    summarise(mean_var = mean(.data[[varcol]]),
              sd_var = sd(.data[[varcol]]))
}
```

I find `get(x)` to be simpler and more intuitive than `!!as.name(x)` or `!!rlang::sym(x)`, and given how volatile all of the quoting/unquoting utilities have been over the last couple of years, a built-in function from the `base` namespace is probably going to be what I turn to for the next couple of years.