# How can I assign a value with case_when() from dplyr based on another column value?

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to assign the value of the column being created using an existing value from another column when using `case_when()` with `mutate()`?

The actual dataframe I'm dealing with is quite complicated so here is a trivial example of what I want:

```
library(dplyr)

df = tibble(Assay = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D"), 
            My_ID = c(3, 12, 36, 5, 13, 1), 
            Modifier = c(12, 6,  5, 9, 3, 6)) 

new_df = df %>% 
  mutate(Assay = case_when(
    My_ID == 5 ~ "C/D",
    My_ID == 12  ~ "Rm",
    My_ID == 13 | My_ID == 3  ~ Modifier * 3,
    TRUE ~ Assay)) %>% 
    select(-Modifier)
```

Expected new_df:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Assay My_ID
  <chr> <dbl>
1 36        3
2 Rm       12
3 B        36
4 C/D       5
5 9        13
6 D         1
```

I can successfully assign the NA values to the column I am mutating when no cases match, but haven't found a way to assign a value based on the value of some other column in the data frame if I'm manipulating it. I get this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Assay`.
i `Assay = case_when(...)`.
x must be a character vector, not a double vector.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you give an expected output? Thanks.

Comment: in Addition, if you have complicated data, you might still want to share a glimpse into it via `dput(head(YOURDATA, 10))` or so, i.e. we need: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The code you are showing in your question is already correct. No need to use paste. If it only works with pate then something is wrong on your end, e.g. maybe another package masking some functions or so. Can you restart R and try your code above again?

Comment: Hi @Lia_G, I ran your example code as you shared it, and it returned your expected result. Using variables is a little different in dplyr than base R. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913673/use-of-get-in-dplyr

Comment: Sorry. I changed it and removed the problem accidently, but was still able to fix it with paste(). Although their may be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that I was able to do this using `paste()` after experimenting. As noted by a commenter, `paste()` works because the underlying issue here is an object type issue. The Assay column is a character vector, but the modification includes an integer. The function `paste()` implicitly converts to a character. The function `paste0()` will fix the problem, but using `as.character()` directly addresses the issue.

```
library(dplyr)

df = tibble(Assay = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D"), 
            My_ID = c(3, 12, 36, 5, 13, 1), 
            Modifier = c(12, 6,  5, 9, 3, 6)) 

new_df = df %>% 
  mutate(Assay = case_when(
    My_ID == 5 ~ "C/D",
    My_ID == 12  ~ "Rm",
    My_ID == 13 | My_ID == 3  ~ as.character(Modifier * 3),
    TRUE ~ Assay)) %>% 
  select(-Modifier)
```

This is the output:

```
 print(new_df)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Assay My_ID
  <chr> <dbl>
1 36        3
2 Rm       12
3 B        36
4 C/D       5
5 9        13
6 D         1
```

Comment: As mentioned above, paste is not required and it should work without it.

Comment: It works with paste() because you were trying to add integers to a column containing characters. The function paste() is converting integer to character, therefore the correct solution is to use as.character() instead of paste(). Please include this information in your answer.